# Call does not continue in onReceive

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I'm having trouble with onReceive of BroadcastReceiver whenever I intercept a call and test for conditions during ringing state. This was working earlier.

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());

Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);      

ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);

if(isForBlocking) {
   telephonyService.silenceRinger();
   telephonyService.endCall();
} else {
  return;
}

...
```

Comment: You're using private APIs of telephonyService.  That's very risky-  they can stop working at any time, as they aren't supposed to be used by general programs.

Comment: @GabeSechan if this is risky, will Google remove those apps available in Play Store that use this? Or they provided already for android SDK?

Comment: Its unlikely they'd remove it from the play store.  They'd just break your app and not care, and not warn you.  Possibly without an alternate way for the same functionality.  Anytime you need to use reflection to get something, be aware it can break at any time.